# Why do we have to port forward for every local resource that we have to access from outsite world,? Why it can't be done without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I was wondering why we have to do port forwarding for every local resource that we need to access from the outer world (by outer world I mean someone else internet connection then ours) For instance, to access ssh of our local machine we have to port forward so that we can access it from outer world. Same goes for CCTV cameras to access them from outer world we have to port forward.

My question is why we have to port forward? Why it can't be done without it?

Comment: Based on your comments, you may be interested in [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53937/8499).

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be done **if** the devices have their own "public" IP addresses – that is, addresses that every client knows how to reach. That's already how many online services work, if the server has a dedicated IP address then it needs no port-forwarding at all.

But in most cases on home (and small business) internet connections, the ISP only provides *one* public IPv4 address for the customer's entire network, and that address is assigned to the customer's main router. All other devices (computers, printers, CCTVs) only get "private" addresses that only make sense within the same network.

So in that situation, when the router receives a connection to its IP address, it has no way of knowing which device you meant to connect to – the only information it has is the TCP port number (service), which says nothing about the intended destination device. Your LAN might have 5 or 10 different devices answering to the same port 80 (HTTP).

So "port forwarding" is needed to create a lookup table from TCP port to internal IP address (usually). If the devices have public IP addresses and not internal ones, then port forwarding is not necessary.

(More accurately, port-forwarding is a *packet rewriting* feature which literally changes the destination address and/or port number inside the packets, but that doesn't say much about why it's needed.)

Recently many ISPs have started adopting IPv6, which has plenty of IP addresses available – allowing each internal device even on a home LAN to have its own publicly reachable address. This again makes port forwarding unnecessary.

(Although on the other hand, you still need to add firewall rules allowing incoming connections – port-forwarding would do this automatically on most routers, but now you need to do it manually, so in the end it's the same amount of configuration...)

Comment: Ok, so from what I have understood. It's necessary because for all incoming connections to my public IP, router won't know where to forward this traffic to my laptop or to my phone? So by port forwarding we explicitly tells it that if an incoming connection is on port XX let it reach to my laptop.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Have you ever thought how great it would have been if we got an option to specify our ip this way. 

`<public_ip>:<local_ip>` former part would have identified my connection and later part would have identified my device.

Comment: I have thought of it, but logically, if you have two 32-bit addresses, that's no different from a single 64-bit address. Indeed I think there were some early IPng proposals to do what you suggest (using IP 'options'), but either way it would have required changes to IPv4 all over the internet – and if you're going to change it, might as well just make the actual address field larger in the first place...

Comment: I guess you can think about it in the opposite way too. In IPv6, we have 128-bit addresses, but since each customer gets _at minimum_ a /64 address prefix, logically you could think of it as 64-bit public address + 64-bit internal address. (And if a business customer gets a /48 prefix, then you can think of it as 48-bit public + 16-bit subnet + 64-bit internal.)

Comment: But address filed actually have got larger (its IPv6 though) have you heard about ngrok? I always wonder how it allows us to do without port forwarding, how does it actually works any idea?

Comment: That would be a separate thread... But in short, Ngrok works almost like a VPN – it always keeps an outbound "tunnel" connection established to the relay servers, and all inbound connections actually happen inside that tunnel. (So your home router doesn't consider them as separate connections – it only sees the outer tunnel.) And the Ngrok relay servers _do_ use port-forwarding – they also have a mapping table from public IP:port to Ngrok client ID.

Comment: Thanks for answering!